# how do i convert timezone string into standard timezone format using php

Tags: php, string, date, time, timezone

**Hi Mates,**

I have a timezone **string** like:

`Mon Nov 05 2012 06:54:06 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time)`

Need to convert these string as below **standard timezone format** using **php**

`(GMT-06:00)-Central America`

**Code**:

```
echo $tz = "Mon Nov 05 2012 06:54:06 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time)";

echo $tz2 = substr($tz, 0, 34);

echo date("P", strtotime("$tz2"));
```

**Results**:

```
Mon Nov 05 2012 06:52:37 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

Mon Nov 05 2012 06:52:37 GMT-0600

+00:00
```

Trying Reference: ***[Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)***

But not resulting such format. Now need help mates, thanks...

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New edit - try this...

```
$tz = "Mon Nov 05 2012 06:54:06 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time)";

$time = explode(" ",$tz);
$timezone = explode("(", str_replace(")","",$tz)); // would be better to use a regex
$new_time = "(".$time[5].")-".$timezone[1];

echo $new_time;  // gives (GMT-0600)-Central America Standard Time
```

Old code before exit.....

```
$tz = "Mon Nov 05 2012 06:54:06 GMT-0600 (Central America Standard Time)";
$new_time = strtotime($tz);

$new_date = date( '(P)-e', $new_time );
echo $new_date;
```

(-05:00)-America/New_York

Comment: It shows like this: `(+00:00)-UTC`, Thus timezone didn't work on `localhost`

Comment: Check the code above, I have updated it. It will only work if the string of date info is the same layout

Answer (score 1):

`echo date("P", strtotime("$tz2"));`

echoes

`GMT-0600`

The name of the region is not available I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried on localhost, its shows: `+00:00`, may didn't work on `localhost`